# Applying higher voltage to WS2815 LEDs to minimize voltage drop

Tags: led-strip

I'm thinking about doing an LED strip project with 12V WS2815 LED strips. I'll have some relatively long runs of LEDs (>10m) and have read about how the voltage drop through the strip requires multiple power injection points along the strip.

I'm curious if using a slightly higher operating voltage, say 13V, would help mitigate some of the voltage drop issues. The WS2815 datasheet says the LEDs can operate at 9.5-13.5V.

I understand I'll still need power injection, but am mostly wondering if this would cause any unforeseen issues while possibly buying me a little extra power delivery to the end of the strips.

Comment: If you're dropping down to 9 volts over the run, the drop needed to cause dimming, I would argue you're so far from in spec that an extra volt or two won't matter. Keep in mind they have built-in CC drivers, so as long as you have the minimum LDO overhead, having more won't affect luminance performance, but could impact longevity.